# ¿Como insertar datos en una sola columna?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, servlets, netbeans-8.2

Quiero insertar en una columna de la tabla `T_tiphab` pero no puedo me dice:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`reservas`.`T_tiphab`, CONSTRAINT `T_tiphab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`codHotel`) REFERENCES `T_hotel` (`codHotel`))

La tabla `T_tiphab` la configure asi:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tipo           | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| numMaxPersonas | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| disponibilidad | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| codHotel       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| precio         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Y la tabla `T_hotel` esta configurada de esta manera:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| codHotel        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| nombre          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fechaMaxEntrada | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numMaxNoches    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Y tiene los siguientes registros:

```
 +----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
 | codHotel | nombre          | fechaMaxEntrada | numMaxNoches |
 +----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
 | 1        | HollydayInn     | NULL            |         NULL |
 | 2        | Sheraton        | NULL            |         NULL |
 | 3        | CincoEstrellas  | NULL            |         NULL |
 | 4        | CuatroEstrellas | NULL            |         NULL |
 | 5        | DosEstrellas    | NULL            |         NULL |
 +----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

¿ Como puedo hacer para insertar en la tabla `T_tiphab` sin que tenga que si o si llenar todas las columnas.?

Comment: Siempre vas a tener que rellenar el campo `codHotel`, con un valor de la base de datos, por eso tiene creada la `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 1):

El error que tienes se debe a la clave foránea que tienes en **t_tiphab**  hacia la tabla de **T_hotel**, el dato que estas ingresando en la columna **codHotel** no existe en dicha tabla. Para arreglar esto asegurate de tener el registro en **T_hotel** o de lo contrario ingresalo. Saludos.

Comment: Es que la tabla hotel tiene ...los datos ( nombre del hotel y su respectiva ID)

Comment: Además no debería aparecer MUL en T_tiphab.?